# Android - Resuming Camera Activity gets delayed

Tags: java, android, performance, camera, android-camera

I was working on Camera Modules, and the only issue here is when I try to retake the camera, it will get delayed for a few secs before opening the Camera Preview again (see First image). Please take a look at my Camera Preview looks below

[image]

This is after i took the photo

[image]

When I click the retake button (middle one), it will take some times to reload the Camera Preview (first image). I've tried another app and found that when it retakes the photo, it will go to previous Camera Preview instantly (without delay), its like going back to previous page.

In Camera Preview, I implemented some canvas draw to create the overlay view. But I think it's not the problem, because the other app that i said previously also takes some times to load the Camera Preview at first. **But, the only different is** when they retake the photo, the Camera Preview will load instantly, while my app takes some times to reload the Camera Preview.

I implemented `SurfaceHolder.Callback` in my Class. I've tried to remove onResume and tweak some of the methods and it didn't help much.

Any idea how to handle this delay?

Thanks

Comment: See my answer hope this will give you some hint.

Comment: thanks @AndyDeveloper, ill check it

Answer (score 1):

You need to create another activity which shows **preview of your capture photo**. Your preview activity XML layout looks same as your capture activity the only difference between both XML Layout is ImageView which you used for preview activity.

Now, how to do that? Here is the simple solution. As you mentioned You used SurfaceHolder.Callback so you have to use the method **Camera.PictureCallback** which save your photo to your storage directory.

```
Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback()
{
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
    {
      // Logic to Save your Photo to your storage directory.
      Intent intent = new Intent(YouActivity.this, PreviewActivity.class);
      // Pass the saved image path to preview activity.
      intent.putExtra("ImagePath", youSavedImagePath);
      startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

Now, on PreviewActivity just get the value from Intent.

```
String imagePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("ImagePath");
```

After getting the path of image set the image to your imageView.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
yourImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Now, When you press back to the CaptureActivity or click on retake your preview will show instantly and not taking time.Please make sure you do not finish the CaptureActivity.

Comment: thanks man, i will update the result and mark as answered once it's success

Comment: @Webster Ya sure. Welcome Sir :)

Comment: anyway, i already implemented similar way with yours, when onPictureTaken I will go to second Activity to load the image that had been taken. Can you elaborate on which part that it will make the retake function faster? thanks dude

Comment: I am afraid this will not solve the problem. The delay is caused by restarting the camera, and activities separation can only make it worse.

Answer (score 1):

For retake to work faster, you can restart camera preview under the hood immediately when the picture arrives, and show the (captured) image view on top, hiding the live camera video stream. If the user decides to retake the photo, you simply hide the overlay (can be a fragment, or just a layout with ImageView and buttons), and the live preview will immediately be available!

Comment: anyway, is there any difference if I use Activity to open the image (Im using Picasso to load the image into the ImageView) rather than using a Fragment?

Comment: As long as you keep both 'scenes' in one Activity, it is much easier to keep track of the Camera lifecycle. Usually, we use SurfaceView callbacks to orchestrate Camera.open(), Camera.release(), startPreview(), etc. It's not impossible to deal with this with a secondary activity, but usually the benefits of separation are significantly less than the advantages of organic camera persistence.